# SQL запрос с EXISTS/NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql

Помогите пожалуйста составить SQL запрос с использованием EXISTS/NOT EXISTS.
Имеется 3 таблицы:

1. Маршрут,
2. Остановка,
3. ОстановкиПоМаршруту

где в ОстановкиПоМаршруту: внешние ключи Маршрут.ID и Остановка.ID являются составным ключем.

Необходимо: **вывести маршруты, которые включают все остановки заданного маршрута**, с использованием операторов EXISTS/NOT EXISTS.

Я сделал этот запрос без вышеперечисленных операторов, который выводит нужный мне результат (СУБД MySQL):

```
SELECT Route.Number, Route.Name 
FROM (SELECT a.Route_ID, COUNT(a.stop_ID) AS Stop_count
    FROM (SELECT Stop_routes.Stop_ID, Stop_routes.Route_ID
        FROM Stop_routes, Route
        WHERE Route.Name = 'Районный'AND Route.ID = Stop_routes.Route_ID) required, (SELECT Stop_routes.Stop_ID, Stop_routes.Route_ID
        FROM Stop_routes) a
        WHERE required.stop_ID = a.stop_ID AND required.Route_ID != a.Route_ID
        GROUP BY (a.Route_ID)) f, (SELECT COUNT(Stop_routes.Stop_ID) AS Stop_count
        FROM Stop_routes, Route
        WHERE Route.Name = 'Районный' AND Route.ID = Stop_routes.Route_ID
        GROUP BY Stop_routes.Route_ID) cnt, Route
WHERE cnt.stop_count = f.stop_count AND f.Route_ID = Route.ID;
```

Запрос выводит все маршруты, которые включают все остановки маршрута "Районный". У меня есть множество примеров с использованием данных операторов, но не могу придумать даже саму логику запроса. Прошу, натолкните на нужные мысли

Comment: Что-то слишком сложный запрос. И очень странное задание. "вывести маршруты, которые включают все остановки заданного маршрута". Т.е. найти маршрут, который полностью включает в себя маршрут "Районный"? Звучит несколько бредово.
А запрос

     SELECT Stop_routes.Stop_ID, Stop_routes.Route_ID
        FROM Stop_routes, Route
        WHERE Route.Name = 'Районный'AND Route.ID = Stop_routes.Route_ID

долже быть идентичен

     SELECT Stop_routes.Stop_ID, Route.ID
        FROM Stop_routes, Route
        WHERE Route.Name = 'Районный'AND Route.ID = Stop_routes.Route_ID

для маршрута "Районный".

Comment: Вот корявый запрос, котоый выдаёт маршруты. имеющие общие остановки с "Районным". С exists

    SELECT c.Number, c.Name
    FROM Route c
    WHERE c.Name <> "Районный" and exists (
        SELECT * 
            FROM Stop_routes JOIN Route ON Stop_routes.Route_ID = Route.ID
            WHERE Stop_routes.Stop_ID in (
                SELECT a.Stop_ID FROM Stop_routes a JOIN Route b
                    ON a.Route_ID = b.ID
                    WHERE b.Name = "Районный") and Route.ID = c.ID)

Comment: Я сделал, вот так:

CREATE VIEW route_stopes AS
SELECT Stop_ID
FROM Stop_routes, route
WHERE Route.Name = 'Районный' AND Route.ID = Stop_routes.route_id;

SELECT Route.name, route.number
FROM Route
WHERE Route.ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT sr.route_id
FROM stop_routes sr
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM route_stopes
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM stop_routes srsrsr WHERE sr.route_id =
srsrsr.route_id and route_stopes.stop_id = srsrsr.stop_id)))
AND Route.name != 'Районный';

Comment: А Вы словами, по-русски это условие описать сможете?

Answer (score 1):

Соответствующая реляционная операция надывается делением. Примеры ее реализации на языке SQL можно найти [здесь](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_relational_division.html), в том числе, и с помощью EXISTS.

Comment: не помогло

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вам нужно готовое решение.
Тогда поможет. :-)

Comment: похоже, что да

Comment: А что вы будете делать со следующей задачей?